# Missing unique Third party identifier

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, identity, open-id-connect, third-party

I am trying to configure Salesforce to use my custom Identity provider(Based on Identity server 3) as oAuth Provider similar to Google. I am able to successfully achieve it but facing one issue with respect to parsing of claims.

my provider token doesn't contain "id" claim in the access token but instead contain "sub" claim to uniquely identify the user. However, if "id" claim is not present in token then Salesforce throws an error saying "Missing third party unique identifier". If i add "id" claim to my token, then it works fine.  I know there is a way in SAML SSO to change the name of the attribute from which Users unique id is read, but is it possible for oAuth provider as well?

I just dont want to include custom claim to my token for supporting Salesforce applications.

Thanks in Advance.